# Regex-based matching and sustitution with nano?

Tags: regex, replace, nano

I am aware of `nano`'s search and replace functionality, but is it capable of using regular expressions for matching and substitution (particularly substitutions that use a part of the match)? If so, can you provide some examples of the syntax used (both for matching and replacing)?

I cut my teeth on Perl-style regular expressions, but I've found that text editors will sometimes come up with their own syntax.

Comment: You can start it with the `-R` flag according to [the nano documentation](http://www.nano-editor.org/dist/v1.2/nano.html#SEC3).

Comment: @gpojd The documentation you link is quite dated. For the version(s) of nano that ship with all modern OSs (as far as I can tell), the -R flag is for "restricted", not "regex" as in the older versions.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to add, or un-comment, the following entry in your global `nanorc` file (on my machine, it was `/etc/nanorc`):

```
set regexp
```

Then fire up a new terminal and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> and do your replacements which should now be regex-aware.

#### EDIT

---

Search for `conf->(\S+)`:

[image]

---

Replace with `\1_conf`

[image]

---

Press `a` to replace all occurrences:

[image]

---

End result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Bart. I have done that, but I'm still getting a "not found" response from nano when I know it should be matching the regex. How would I translate the following Perl regex into something nano would understand? `s/conf->(\S+)/$1_conf/`

Comment: @Daniel, added some screen-shots.

Comment: Thanks, this worked great on my Ubuntu machine. Unfortunately, it did not work on my Mac. The version that ships with Snow Leopard is 2.0.x, whereas Ubuntu is using the latest stable (2.2.x). I even tried compiling from the latest stable source code, but still the regexp is not working on my Mac. Oh well...

Comment: Thanks a lot! Instead of editing the config file, you can also press Meta+R (Alt+R) while in search to toggle regex search on/off.

Comment: Mac keyboard "Meta+R" (Option-R) is the Registered Trademark ®.  In Terminal change this in  Preferences, Profiles tab, Keyboard subtab (on right), checkbox at the bottom "Use Option as Meta key".

Comment: For those without super user access or those who don't want to mess up config for other users edit $HOME/.nanorc instead

Answer (score 31):

My version of nano has an option to swtich to regex search with the `meta` character + `R`. In cygwin on Windows, the meta-key is `alt`, so I hit `ctrl`+`\` to get into search-and-replace mode, and then `alt`+`r` to swtich to regex search.

Comment: +1 for the alt+r.  This is half the real answer.  @SPArifSahariWibowo has the bigger half.

Comment: For those who use Mac: http://osxdaily.com/2013/02/01/use-option-as-meta-key-in-mac-os-x-terminal/

Comment: this combined with S P Arif Sahari Wibowo's answer is the correct answer IMO

Comment: For those with German keyboard: It's Strg-AltGr-\ because you need AltGr to get the backslash.

Comment: On Ubuntu, I did ^w (to search) and Alt+R made it regexp.

Comment: I just had to use "Alt+R" TWICE the first time to make sure I was in regexp search mode. You only need to hit that once the next times. It should say `[Regexp]` if you are in the right mode.

Answer (score 17):

The regular expression format / notation for nano use "*Extended Regular Expression*", i.e. *POSIX Extended Regular Expression*, which is used by `egrep` and `sed -r`, this include metacharacters `.`, `[` and `]`, `^`, `$`, `(`, `)`, `\1` to `\9`, `*`, `{` and `}`, `?`, `+`, `|`, and character classes like `[:alnum:]`, `[:alpha:]`, `[:cntrl:]`, `[:digit:]`, `[:graph:]`, `[:lower:]`, `[:print:]`, `[:punct:]`, `[:space:]`, `[:upper:]`, and `[:xdigit:]`.

For more complete documentation you can see manual page, `man 7 regex` in Linux or `man 7 re_format` in OS X. This page may give you same information as well: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_basic_and_extended

Unfortunately in nano there seems to be no way to match anything that span across multiple lines.

Comment: +1 for the multiline clue.  

And `$1` doesn't work in the second string but `\1` does! (For parenthetical subexpressions.)  

Neither `\n` nor `[:newline:]` seems to work in the second string.

Comment: Nano has it's own start/end commands to capture groups which span multiple lines. A C-style block comment could be defined as:

color brightblack start="/\\*" end="\\*/"

Comment: Regular character classes did not seem to work for me. So `[:digit:]` works while `\d` did not. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit old, just updating the search index.

Nano 5.5 uses the `ASCII` column from this same table.

Thanks to @S P Arif Sahari Wibowo ,

I found the answer here anyway (same wiki link):
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_basic_and_extended

Answer (score 0):

I was recently faced with the problem of inserting text at the beginning of everyline that started with a numerical digit. For that the only way to distinguish this from text i didn't want to change was the previous new line.

Playing around with the information provided in this answer I was able to do it and decided to add it to the answer in case somebody else faces the same situation.

To search for the beginning of the line followed by a number and then insert "Text String" at the beginning of each line that starts with a number:

\ then "(^[0-9])"  press carry return, then: "Text String 1" press carry return and the select yes, if it does what you want next press a for all. Omit the " quotation marks.