# How to add dots between every two digits of a six digit substring?

Tags: regex, datetime, rename, filenames, nano

I have a text file that contains roughly a thousand file names that I need to change slightly. Each file name is a date and time formatted like:

```
2013-05-01 120125.jpg
```

I need to convert all of them to:

```
2013-05-01 12.01.25.jpg
```

I'm assuming this would be fairly trivial with regular expressions, but I am always confounded when I try to do anything with them! Help is appreciated!

Comment: What have you tried? Show your work. SO is not a code writing service, you have to do your own work and we can help you fix the problems you encounter.

Comment: What language/environment will be running this regex?

Comment: I'll most likely be running the regex in nano. What I'm trying to do is to bulk change file names using renameutils. This opens a nano file with all the filenames in the folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use a replace technique (in whatever language/environment you are using) on your substrings by capturing like this:

```
(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})
```

*note the curly brackets are for improved efficiency.

And replace with:

```
$1.$2.$3
```

Here is a [demo link](https://regex101.com/r/qC0Put/2).

Here is a [SO page discussing the execution of replacements on nano](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745535/regex-based-matching-and-sustitution-with-nano).

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a go.

Answer (score 0):

Use capture groups to match the digits, and copy them to the replacement.

Replace: `(\d\d)(\d\d)(\d\d)\.jpg`

With: `$1.$2.$3.jpg`

`$1`, `$2`, `$3` copy the parts of the original string that each capture group matched.

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned  by Soviut, SO is for help and not doing the work for you.  That being said:

If you want to do something with Regular Expressions you're best going to the Rubular website which allows you to create your regex whilst seeing exactly what result you're getting.

[Rubular](http://rubular.com/)

Comment: Something tells me this "answer" shouldn't be here, but in the comment section instead... oh

Comment: Thanks, I'll read up. I wasn't trying to avoid learning it... well maybe a little... I just always feel very overwhelmed with regex. This isn't homework help or anything, just trying to merge some files.